# Do not disturb Setting for emails

Tags: iphone

i have an iphone 5s with ios 8.1 and would like to silent my phone at night and only to sound when i receive and email sent to my specific email address. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can set 'Do Not Disturb' mode for specific times, & allow phone calls from chosen people, or from anyone who calls twice in quick succession, but I know of no way to do that for email.

[image]